# How are OBJECT fields handled in Mongo indexes?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query

In Mongo, if I override the default _id field like:

```
{
  _id: {
    userId: 123,
    accountId: 123
  }
}
```

Are the _id fields each individually indexed, or is the index rendered useless? For example, if I were to search for a document where user Id is 123 and account Id is 456, does the index even offer any value?

Lastly - for the uniqueness requirement, I presume each document will have a brand new _id document, even if the fields are identical. Intuitively, this would seem to just do referential equality. Is that correct?

Comment: Though you can use any data type for the `_id` (except array types), it generally not recommended to use the `object` type. The index is on the entire object. and not on individual fields.

Comment: Does the index even do anything at that point?

Comment: Any type of fields can be indexed - even array fields. And, they do their job. How indexes work on different field types is something you need to understand before you put it use in your work. For object types, you can _also_ define indexes on individual fields - if that is something you need also.

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB internally uses BSON for storage.

See [Comparison/Sort Order](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-type-comparison-order/#objects) for how objects are compared.

These objects would all be different, and so would not violate the uniqueness constraint for _id:

```
{userId: 123, accountId:123}
{userId: 123}
{accountId: 123}
{accountId: 123, userId: 123}
```